# Whats differents between WebService and WCF?

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, sharepoint

Whats differents between WebService and WCF?

I dont understand differents. Is WCF better than WebService?
For example, i want to create service on Sharepoint- what should i use?

Thank you.

Comment: Check this - http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/10-differences-between-wcf-and

Comment: Also check this out: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b109be26-019a-4876-ba27-2bc66e974278/what-is-the-difference-between-wcf-service-and-windows-service?forum=wcf

Comment: WCF is a framework where you can configure Webservice and other communication service.

Answer (score 2):

It's like comparing apples to <strike>oranges</strike> fire extinguishers. WCF is, as its name says, a communication framework. It lets your clients and servers communicate with each other. It is that simple, it is meant to be that simple. The communication can happen through named pipes, binary TCP sockets, or HTTP web services. (Also you can have a WCF-based webservice, but you can develop webservices without it, like ASP.NET .asmx services.) The protocol is one aspect of the communication, there are others as well. You only have to be concerned about configuring what you want to use, WCF will do the rest. About the SharePoint part, [take a look at this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff521586.aspx). ([According to this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms464040.aspx), ASP.NET webservices are deprecated.)